Facing this issue in my wordpress website : Content loaded from: ehpollmany.info (Google Ads)
I have scan everything in website but i' not able to find this issue.I have install the plugin and find some virus. i have removed that virus. Try all tools but i'm not able to find that URL in the website hall. i have checked in the database also but there is no URL.

Quite unclear what you are asking about. Please go read [ask], and then add some more detail to your question.

@CBroe Facing the issue with google ads approval because of this link: ehpollmany.info

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That still doesn't tell us much more, than your initial question already did. What plugin are you talking about? What "virus"? If you got your system infected with something malicious - then it probably won't contain that URL or domain name in clear text, but will have it encoded or obfuscated somehow, to try and avoid detection.

@CBroe We are facing an issue with the Google ads approval. my ads are disapproved of this issue. After the google team reviewed my ads it simply said that the content loaded from: ehpollmany.info (Google Ads)) but they didn't provide the correct URL where they found that particular URL.
